How to Wireshark know the URL in the quic initial packet

enter image description here

I don't do any decryption method.
Capture QUIC，I can see the url in "Decrypted QUIC" and "Reassembled TLS Handshake"
Isn't http3 already solving the problem that existed in previous versions? There isn't much plaintext information in the packet, like SNI. Why does Wireshark know the URL?How does that?

SNI visible in HTTP/3, QUIC connection
